# why this c program can't compile factorial

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int FAC(int a)
{
    if (a >= 1, a--)
    {
        return a + 1 * a;
        FAC(a);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int a = 0;
    int ret = 0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    ret = FAC(a);
    printf("%d\n", ret);
}
```

if I input `5` the outcome is `8`

But in the first function should't it be

5>=1 5-1 return 5*4 4>=1...

Comment: The `return` statement returns *immediately*. any statements after that will not be executed.

Comment: I also recommend you study more about recursion, how it works and how to use it.

Comment: By the way, the statement `if (a >= 1, a--)` is the same as `if (a--)`. The [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) throws away the result of the left-hand side sub-expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're returning a value *before* you're using recursion. The `return` keyword takes effect immediately, so all statements following this won't be executed.

Also, your factorial function does not actually calculate the factorial of `a`.

**Examples for factorial functions:**

Recursive

```
int factorial(int n) {
  if(n > 0) {
    return n * factorial(n - 1); // n! = n * (n-1) * (n-2) * ... * 1
  } else {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Iterative

```
// Does exactly the same, just an iterative function
int factorial(int n) {
  int fac = 1;
  for(; n > 0; n--) {
    fac *= n;
  }
  return fac;
}
```

Comment: `if(n > 0)`, this can be changed to `if (n > 1)`.

Comment: BTW, what if I call `FAC(-1)`? Should that be allowed - it will return 1?

Comment: @kiner_shah no, `if(n > 0)` is correct, this depends on the context.
In this code, only positive numbers will return a correct value; this is just an example code and was made to let the author of this question understand how factorial actually works.

Comment: @kiner_shah and yes, calling one of these functions with any negative integer will return `1`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>  

int FAC(int a)
{
    if (a < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        if (a == 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return (a * FAC(a-1));
        }
    }
} 

int main()  
{  
  int a = 0;  
  int ret = 0;  
  scanf("%d", &a);   
  ret = FAC(a);
  if (ret == -1) {
    printf("%s\n", "Input was a negative integer.");
  } else {    
    printf("%d\n", ret); 
  }
}
```

Comment: BTW, what if I call `FAC(-1)`?

Comment: Then the program would never terminate because the argument passed to FAC function will never reach 0.

Comment: @Edmund well it would...eventually. it would be UB because of signed integer wraparound, but eventually it will get to 0 and return some nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Your factorial function (`FAC`) should ideally be something like:

```
unsigned int FAC(unsigned int a)
{
    // base condition - break out of recursion
    if (a <= 1)
        return 1;

    return a * FAC(a - 1);
}
```

`unsigned int` restricts range of argument to be in `[0, UINT_MAX]`.

Do note that `FAC` returns a `unsigned int`, so you may be able to provide argument value up to 12, else there will be an overflow and you can see weird output.

BTW, `UINT_MAX` is defined in `limits.h`